# Date difference in tab and mobile

Tags: android

I was trying to retrieve the current week of the month

```
    TimeZone timezone = TimeZone.getDefault();
    Calendar c = new GregorianCalendar(TimeZone.getTimeZone("GMT"));
    c.set(year, month, day);
    // Set the calendar to monday of the current week
    c.set(Calendar.DAY_OF_WEEK, Calendar.SUNDAY);
    c.add(Calendar.DATE, num * 7);
    // Print dates of the current week starting on Monday
    SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd", Locale.ENGLISH);
    String[] days = new String[7];
    for (int i = 0; i < 7; i++) {
        days[i] = df.format(c.getTime());
        c.add(Calendar.DAY_OF_MONTH, 1);
    }
    return days;
```

where yr mnth and day will abe passed as parameters of the function... and the num value will be laways-1. It return the proper value in phone. But in tab I am getting the previous week. The OS of both devices are same as well as date and time zone..

Please share if you guys have any solutions

Comment: c.add(Calendar.DATE, num * 7);

if num value is -1 and you are setting date to -7, arent you supposed to get previous week.

Comment: Actually I am getting the correct value in phone.I tested it with motog motoe and nexus.. I am getting this trouble only in tablets